# Postgres add user impossible

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I get from customer Postgres 8.4, a very strange edition

[image]

I login with Postgres user under trust settings.
But in pgAdmin i got a lot of relations errors
[image]
[image]

I thought normally tables should goes to DB Catalogs Tables, but here DB Catalogs Tables not exists or i cant see them, all tables i see in db Schemas, and database is working as i can access it through ODBC and Postgres connector, but then i see all 2809 tables i a row without separation.  It like multi tenat services, but misconfigured or not suit with pgAdmin.

From pgAdmin i cant create any user and roles, from ssh psql created user cant connect through odbc or Postgres connector, and do not appears in pgAdmin Login/Group Roles tab.

[image]
[image]

[image]

1. So why i cant access in pgAdmin4 Login/Group Roles tab?
2. Why cant create user from pgAdmin4?
3. Why cant access pg_catalogs from pgAdmin4?
4. Why user created from ssh psql cant access database from ODBC or Postgres connector? (got always table is empty)
5. If this is multi tenant services why it not work like expected from pgAdmin?

PgAdmin 4 version 5.6

Answer (score 1):

PgAdmin4 says it supports 9.5 and newer.  8.4 is not newer than 9.5.